# REST API endpoint for linkedin automation on make.com

Tags: linkedin-api

Would highly appreciate help on this! For my business linked in page I am looking to create an automation where my facebook multiple image posts automatically get sent to linkedin and creates image posts for me. We need one piece of information so all of the photos from the post get transfered over to linkedin.

We need help on how to use your REST API endpoint. The goal is to be able to upload multiple images to the page from facebook. Can can someone help with this please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It appears to me that multiple images in one LinkedIn Post are not possible. For me only one image per post is working.